# How to efficiently catch an exception and check if argument is not None

Tags: python, exception

Imagine that you have a function that in some error cases gives exceptions and in some returns None (it was not designed by me and I need to use it). Now, you need to handle these errors, but in an identical way (show a message to a user, log it and gracefully quit).

I've been doing something like this:

```
try:
    result = weird_func()
except:
    *same functionality* do something here

if not result:
    *same functionality* do the same here as in the except block
```

But it's really awful. Is there a way to cleverly roll these two into one?
I've been thinking about using try/finally without except, but it looks kind of weird.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the `*same functionality*` into a function, and call the function in both places.

Comment: In general, your function should be able to handle any type of input it gets with out raising errors.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to have a bare `except` (there are some unusual special cases, e.g., there's one in `subprocess` after it forks, but in general, catch the exceptions you care about, rather than "every possible exception including `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try:
    result = weird_func()
except TheExceptionYouWantToCatch:
    result = None

if result is None:
    #Whatever you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting result to `None` is an option.

```
try:
    result = weird_func()
except:
    result = None

if not result:
    *same functinality* do the same here as in the except block
```

or raising exception in `try`.

```
try:
    result = weird_func()
    if not result: raise Exception() # or assert result
except:
    *same functinality* do something here
```

Comment: In your second example, shouldn't it be `if not result:`?

Answer (score 0):

more or less what falsetru said:

```
result = wierd_func()
assert result
```

will raise either the original exception or an AssertionError when result is None.  As long as any enclosing try can catch AssertionErrror as well as whatever else wierd_func does you're good.

for the sake of completeness there's also:

```
try:
   return wierd_func() or RuntimeError() # or whatever you'd like to raise:
except:
   return sys.exc_info()[0]
```

which would always return an exception object in the case of an error, so you could do the recovery that way --- however I would not bother: try/catch is for handling error conditions so add the assert and then handle all exceptions in one place

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the same pattern as in [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18071825/1256452)'s answer.  For some unusual cases, especially ones having to do with files, I sometimes use a slightly modified version, something like this:

```
to_close = None
stream = None
try:
    to_close = open(path, mode)
    stream = to_close
    if validate_open_stream(stream):
        to_close = None
finally:
    if to_close is not None:
        to_close.close()
        stream = None
return stream
```

This particular sequence allows me to open a file (which may raise `IOError` if the file cannot be opened), then inspect it in some way—make sure it has a proper "magic number", for instance—and then return the open stream for further use.  If something goes wrong while the file is open, `to_close` is non-`None` at the `finally` clause and I close the stream and make sure to return `None`.

(Usually a context manager is more appropriate for this; I needed that pattern more for Python 2.4 and earlier.)